# What are those symbols in IL code?

Tags: c#, .net, intermediate-language

What is this symbol ( `IL_0000` etc) in the IL code. its this the real memory heap address?

```
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "here is something"
  IL_0006:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_000b:  nop
  IL_000c:  ldc.i4.s   18
  IL_000e:  newobj     instance void Proj.Stock::.ctor(int32)
  IL_0013:  stloc.0
  IL_0014:  ldstr      "another"
  IL_0019:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_001e:  nop
  IL_001f:  ldstr      "and even more"
  IL_0024:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0029:  nop
  IL_002a:  ret
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IL_0000:` is a Code Label.  It's really just an identifier so you can easily reference jump locations by name instead of by byte count.

See the Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) standard documents. 
**[ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) section II.5.4**

> **II.5.4 Labels and l ists of labels**
>
> Labels are provided as a programming convenience; they represent a
>   number that is encoded in the metadata. The value represented by a
>   label is typically an offset in bytes from the beginning of the
>   current method, although the precise encoding differs depending on
>   where in the logical metadata structure or CIL stream the label
>   occurs.
>
> ...

Comment: It also has the interesting side effect of showing you the size of every instruction (since the numbers are relative addresses).

Comment: True... if you are using ILDASM... but that's not a requirement.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - So at label `IL_0001`, its doing a `ldstr` on the string `here is something`. The next label is `IL_0006`. However, `here is something` is 17 characters long and stored as unicode (2 bytes per character), that's 34 bytes. So shouldn't the next label be `IL_0023` (35 in hex)?

Comment: A reference to the string is stored after the opcode.  Not the string its self.

Comment: @MatthewWhited - Gotcha! Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: It's the same reason the `call` opcodes are 5 bytes long.  They also use a 32bit reference to the method and not the method name.